# Настройка элемента в CSS через span?

Tags: css

Нужно как то через CSS найти все элементы, у которых span - "Версия: Test"

```html
<div class="main-cardSubHeader-root main-type-mesto" as="div" style="color: var(--spice-subtext);"><span>Версия: Test</span></div>
```

По классу нельзя, ибо есть ещё и такое, и нужно что бы они не затрагивались

```html
<div class="main-cardSubHeader-root main-type-mesto" as="div" style="color: var(--spice-subtext);">2021</div>
```

Я пробовал

```
[span="Версия: Test"] {}
```

Но это ничего не дало

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то это невозможно.

Comment: @OliverPatterson , а можно ли тогда как нибудь сделать так, что бы при помощи "display: none" фраза "Версия: Test" вообще нигде никогда не показывалась? Раз по span не получается настроить именно тут

Comment: С помощью JS можно. Но результат будет виден после загрузки страницы.

Comment: @OliverPatterson , Подскажите пожалуйста, как?

Comment: Данный текст только в span может быть? И именно "Версия: Test"?

Comment: @OliverPatterson , Да

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.main-cardSubHeader-root.main-type-mesto span
{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-cardSubHeader-root main-type-mesto" as="div" style="color: var(--spice-subtext);"><span>Версия: Test</span></div>
<div class="main-cardSubHeader-root main-type-mesto" as="div" style="color: var(--spice-subtext);">2021</div>
```

Comment: Увы. Не работает :c

Comment: Есть шанс, что контент подгружается после загрузки страницы?

Comment: Да
............

Comment: Отредактировал.

Comment: Всё равно не работает :c
Возможно, тут проблемы с принятием скриптов, по крайней мере в таком виде. Потому с самого начала и хотел на CSS... Ладно, спасибо в любом случае.

Comment: В элементе с классом ```main-cardSubHeader-root main-type-mesto``` span находится, только если там написано "версия .." или может просто так встретится?

Comment: Только если там написано

Comment: Если нужно скрыть только span, то обновил ответ.

Comment: Вот. Теперь работает. Огромное спасибо))
К слову, нет ли желания помочь ещё с несколькими подобными вещами? За денюжку, разумеется. Но остальные так просто на словах, вслепую не объяснить. Нужно будет софт и утилиту к нему поставить.